# Applying conditional formatting to non-contiguous selections in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In Excel, I can make multiple selections on a spreadsheet, and use conditional formatting to apply a color scale which includes all of my selections.

With openpyxl, in order to apply conditional formatting, I need a range string:

```
rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type="min", start_color="FFFFFF", 
                      end_type="max", end_color="247CBD")
range_string = "A1:D10"
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add(range_string, rule)
```

If I try to use a range string to select non-contiguous areas using the normal Excel notation, eg:

```
range_string = "A1:D10,A20:D30"
```

then the format does not get applied, the cells remain unformatted.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

Use a space as the delimiter instead of a comma.

```
range_string = "A1:D10 A20:D30"
```

This is the same format as used in the XML, but not the same as in Excel itself, hence the confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. I tried "," and ";". But the space is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to apply the format to the different ranges:

```
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add("A1:D10", rule)
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add("A20:D30, rule)
```

I've never seen non-contiguous ranges in the source files so I suspect that this is what Excel does if you pass multiple ranges in.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that when I do this, the color scale doesn't get applied over all selections, I just end up with a bunch of different areas, each with their own color scales. I want a continuous color scale over separate areas of cells.